# ListView Adapter with arbitrary number of row types (Don't know the number of different row types)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

So, I am making this application. The application parses a website, or more specifically a vbulletin-board. When I'm parsing a thread in the forum, I have divided it up so that when I parse each post in that thread, I get the actual content of the post in sections such as this, and I store the sections in the correct order in an array:

```
[Plain text]
[Quote from somebody]
[Plain text]
[Another quote]
[Another quote again]
[Some more plain text]
```

However, a post can be arranged in any order as you might know, and can consist of more or fewer sections than in the example, and it doesn't have to have quotes in it either, or it might just be one or several quotes. Anything is possible.

When I list the posts in my application, I am using a ListView. Each row of this listview will then *always* consist of a header, and any combination of the previously mentioned sections.

The way I was thinking of doing it after googling a bit about it is to have one "Base-layout" with just a layout-tag in one XML-file, and a separate layout for each section, stored in separate XML-files, and at each call to getView() in my adapter, look at the post at that position in my "Post-list", and then loop through the sections in that particular post, and inflate a new "Quote-layout" for each quote-section stored in the post, and inflate a "Plain-text-layout" for each plain-text-section in the post. And for each of those I fill in all the content belonging to that post.

I think this would work, but there might be a performance problem? As I understand it layout inflation is quite expensive, and I won't be able to recycle the View passed in to getView() either, since it might have a bunch of sections added to it that I might not need in another call to getView().. That is, if I understand getView() and the recycling somewhat.

**This is a basic example of what I mean with the getView() method of the adapter:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // Inflate the base-layout, which the others are added to.
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.forum_post,null);

    View header = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_header_layout, null);
    View message = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_text_layout, null);
    View quote = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_quote_layout, null);

    ((ViewGroup)view).addView(header);
    ((ViewGroup)view).addView(message);
    ((ViewGroup)view).addView(quote);
    return view;
}
```

And then inflate more quote-views/message-views as needed when I extract the data from my list of saved posts.

The base-layout is just a LinearLayout-tag

The layouts I inflate are just RelativeLayouts with some TextViews and an ImageView added.

This code produces this result, where I have a *Header* with
username, picture, etc.., One section of *Plain text*, and one *Quote-section*.
This doesn't seem to work properly all the time though, because when I tried it out just now a copy of the list seemed to get stuck on the background and another one scrolled on top of it..

http://s14.postimg.org/rizid8q69/view.png

Is there a better way to do this? Because I imagine this isn't very efficient

Comment: you want inflate different layouts for your rows in listview?

Answer (score 5):

You need to override `getViewItemType` and `getViewTypeCount`.

`getItemViewType(int position)` - returns information which layout type you should use based on position

Then you inflate layout only if it's null and determine type using `getItemViewType`.

Example :

```
   private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 0;
   private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 1;
   private static final int TYPE_ITEM3 = 2;
    @Override; 
    public int getItemViewType(int position) 
    {
    int type;
    if (position== 0){ // your condition
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;  //type 0 for header
    } else if(position == 1){
        type = TYPE_ITEM2; //type 1 for message
    }else {
        type = TYPE_ITEM3; //type 2 for Quote
    }
    return type;
    }
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;    //three different layouts to be inflated
}
```

In `getView`

```
 int type= getItemViewType(i); // determine type using position.
 switch (type) {
 case TYPE_ITEM1: 
    view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_header_layout, null);   // inflate layout for header
 break;
 case TYPE_ITEM2:
     view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_text_layout, null); //   inflate layout for quote
 break;
 case TYPE_ITEM3:
      quote = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_quote_layout, null);  //   inflate layout for message
 break;    
 ....
```

You need to use a View Holder for smooth scrolling and performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

You can check the tutorial below

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: @user1944184 without knowing how can you inflate the layouts?

Comment: I think you misunderstand? Because I used those two methods in another adapter when I knew I had exactly two different types of rows. 
But this time each of the types in your getItemViewType() is not a separate row in the ListView, they are each a separate row within a row in the ListView, and there can be an arbitrary number of type2 and type3 rows within a ListView row.

Already checked the tutorial, but it didn't help because my rows in my list is not a set number of different types

Maybe I didn't explain my problem very good..
Maybe I have to do it programmatically instead

Comment: @user1944184 wow!. i really don't understand your problem. sorry can't help further.

Comment: My previous reply was a misclick, do you remember what you answered?

Edit: Alright :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to reuse `convertView` that has been passed as one of the argument. This way you can avoid inflating the item `View`.

Secondly, you could use something as `ViewHolder` to store references to your inner `View`s. Using `ViewHolder` will increase performance whether you are inflating view or finding them by id as both methods are very expensive.

Set the `ViewHolder` as a Tag on item `View`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // if possible reuse view
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_header_layout, null));
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // reuse view
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    //set text, listeners, icon, etc.

    return view;
}
```

The `ViewHolder` is just private inner class storing referenced to view.

private static class ViewHolder {

```
    private final View view;

    private ViewHolder(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

Talk about `ListView` usage was given at [Google IO 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=708s).

Answer (score 0):

The inflater needs to know the real type of the futur parent ViewGroup, therefore the following code is erroneous:

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.forum_post,null);
```

and instead, you should use this one:

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.forum_post,viewGroup,false);
```

Same thing for the other `inflate`: use the real parent (`view` in this case) or another viewGroup which is of the same type as the (futur) parent; otherwise the LayoutParameters will not be set to the right type and the values that you have specified in your XML code will be lost (never used).