# Android: ListView add label in getView()?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am a beginner. And I've tried a lot but I don't know how I can do this:

I have an **ArrayAdapter**. That displays all items and `if position == 3` it should display also a label.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView;
    if (position == 3){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_date, parent, false);

        // set text of label ...

        // now I want to display also the normal item
    } else {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list, parent, false);

        // set text of item ...

    }

    return rowView;
}
```

It displays the label but I don't know how I can also show the normal item if it shows the label. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370525/listview-adapter-with-arbitrary-number-of-row-types-dont-know-the-number-of-di/17370772#17370772. check this if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan that`s definitely the way

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a new layout which would contains both the `event_date` and `events_lists`

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView;
    if (position == 3){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_date_plus_events_list, parent, false);

        // set text of label ...


    } else {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list, parent, false);

    }

        // set text of item ...

    return rowView;
}
```