# how to display a message using listview for both side of layout in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

In my application i went to display a messages like this

pls tell me ,how to display message in list view ,and how to display a list view 
one is left and other one is right

and how to display a time in bottom of the message

**pls see my code**

```
    //view display 
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    AllmessagedispalyContants message = (AllmessagedispalyContants) this.getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.allmessagesms, null);



        holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        holder.date=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
    holder.date.setText(message.getDate());


    LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();
    lp = (LayoutParams)holder.date.getLayoutParams();

    //check if it is a status message then remove background, and change text color.
    if(message.isStatusMessage())
    {
        holder.message.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textFieldColor);
    }
    else
    {   
        //Check whether message is mine to show green background and align to right

        if(message.messageType.equals(bool))
        {

            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

        }
        //If not mine then it is from sender to show orange background and align to left
        else
        {

            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lift);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        }
        holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
        holder.message.setTextSize(14);
        Typeface typface=Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        holder.message.setTypeface(typface);

        //holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textColor);   
    }
    return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView message;
    TextView date;



}
```

[image]

Comment: you need have have a custom listview. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370525/listview-adapter-with-arbitrary-number-of-row-types-dont-know-the-number-of-di/17370772#17370772. two layouts one for the left image one for right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write a custom adapter and in the get view method depending on the position value you can return the corresponding layouts with the image place either on the left or right. For instance every odd number place the image on the left and the message on the right.

```
if((position%2)==0
 // even display the image on the right
else
   // odd display the image on the left.
```

To give you an idea,
create an layout as below with the image on the left:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create another layout with the image on the right:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the get view method as mentioned earlier you can do the following:

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if((position%2)==0{
        // even display the image on the right.
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.image_right_layout, null);
        }else{
        // odd display the image on the left.
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.image_left_layout, null);
        }

        return view;
```

}

You will have to change the code to set content into the views.

Comment: Pls follow the urls provided above should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Adaptor for your list view and create a layout with 2 textview and 2 image for listview row(one for sender and one for receiver).
Now using database you can preserve the message and the status whether it is from sender side and receiver side. According to that you can decide which ImageView and which EditText you want to show which one you want to hide

Basically you need this :

1) 2 ImageView (one for receiver another for sender) 
2) 2 EditText or TextView one for receiver another for sender) 
3) Database to save your message entry and display it on your UI through listview

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Your Speech"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" 
            >

        </TextView>

        <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="sender's Speech"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" 
            >

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

when you set the visibility of receiver speech textview to "invisible" and imageview to "invisible" you will get this layout:

[image]

And when you set the visibility of your speech textview to "gone" and imageview to "invisible" you get this layout:

[image]

Set this layout to your listview row. Hope this will help.