# Make first ListView item appear in a different layout

Tags: android, listview, getview

I'm trying to make a **ListView with the first item displayed in a different layout**, and others in a common layout. Both layouts have the same elements which in pairs have the same names. When I do like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        
    if(convertView == null) {
        if(position == 0){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_top_item, parent, false);
            Log.d("ALA", "pos = " + position + ", inflated top");
        }
        else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_item, parent, false);
            Log.d("ALA", "pos = " + position + ", inflated normal");
        }
    }
    // setText, setBitmap etc here
    return convertView;
}
```

it didn't work. 
From the log I could say, `inflater.inflate` was triggered 6 times, `inflated top` 1 time and `inflated normal` 5 times.

What displayed is, article[0] was in layout `article_list_top_item` and article[1] ~ article[5] was in `article_list_item`.

Up until here it's ok, but the pattern repeated, which means article[6], article[12], [18],... were all in the layout `article_list_top_item` which is not what I want.

**What can I do to make ONLY the first article to appear in** `article_list_top_item`??

P.S. I tried renaming elements in `article_list_top_item.xml` and if-branched the `setText` `setImage` process, didn't help.

I tried adding `else return convertView;` before `//setText` lines, it became a mess.

I thought of making a dedicated layout element for the first item only, but that's not what I want because the whole list lays under a `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Please help.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566512/best-way-to-build-and-handle-list-view-with-differing-rows

Comment: Thanks @Blackbelt, this solved the problem. Not that I haven't searched before I post, but I was too distracted by all those posts about ViewHolders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use different itew view type. Your adapter reuse the view already inflated, so if you want to different kind you should tell him :

Create a holder for each of your view type

```
private class FirstHolder {
    //add a field for each subview in view type 1
}
private class SecondHolder {
    //add a field for each subview in view type 2
}
```

Override the `getViewTypeCount()` method

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Override the `getItemViewType(int position)` method. This method tells which type of view is used for each position.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Build and setup the view :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (position == 0) {
        FirstHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new FirstHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever_firstlayout, parent, false);
            //for each field of holder find the subview
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (FirstHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //set the data in subview with holder fields
    } else {
        SecondHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new SecondHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever_secondlayout, parent, false);
            //for each field of holder find the subview
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (SecondHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //set the data in subview with holder fields
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, with one addition: please implement the ViewHolder pattern. ListViews should NOT even exist without it.

Comment: In the case of having multiple view types, you can make the same number of ViewHolder model classes

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the point of having a holder here. It only helps assigning data to layout elements, which is not what I'm having trouble upon. I'm still having the correct data assigned to the correct element in my layout, just that I need only the first item to appear differently.

Comment: Thanks @sonic, I overrided getViewTypeCount only

Answer (score 1):

You can use addHeaderView. For example;

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View head = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerlayout, listview, false);
listview.addHeaderView(head);
```

Comment: I solved the problem before trying this, but this can make a great reference later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Exactly like @sonic said, I want to use different kinds of views for the same ListView so I have to tell him so, by overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)`. Working code:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount(){
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos){
    return pos > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View listItem, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(listItem == null) 
        listItem = inflater.inflate(getItemViewType(position) == 0 ?
                   R.layout.article_list_top_item : R.layout.article_list_item
                   , parent, false);
    // setText setBitmap etc. here
}
```

Comments: It works even if I don't use `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` anywhere, but overriding them matters. Doubting 
`getItemViewType(int position)` would do anything, I tried not overriding it - and the result is, I had to override both to make it work.

I wonder how. Maybe everytime the view is inflated with a layout that's never used before, then the system assign that layout with a number from 0 to `getViewTypeCount() - 1`? Otherwise, where have it been used (in parent classes' code) to make it matter?

I'll leave this here to think later.